# Is there an accepted method to determine if a string is a valid connection string?

Tags: c#

I have a command line app that will be configured in one of two ways:

1. XML file
2. SQL Server database (specifically Microsoft SQL Server, not a generic "SQL database")

To set the config, it will be called with a `config` command line argument.

```
myapp.exe -config [some file path]
myapp.exe -config [some connection string]
```

So, I will get a string inside the app, and I'll need to figure out which one it is.

Is there an accepted way to determine if a given string is a valid SQL connection string?  I'd love to take either of the two options as the same argument, then just internally figure out if it's a (1) file path, or (2) connection string.

Is there some way to do this, or should I just attempt to locate a file at the path, and assume it's a connection string if the file isn't found?  Or vice-versa?

Comment: No. Because every DBMS has its more or less own syntax and custom properties. Have a look on [https://www.connectionstrings.com/](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) and compare a few

Comment: easiest way: try to get an object using `Path.GetFileName` object from the string; if that fails it must be connection string so use it to connect to a database. if that fails the user messed up. you must know the DBMS though.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have mentioned that we can always assume SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File names can't contain an equal sign. Connection strings *always* contain equal signs. (It becomes the accepted method if you accept it.)

It's important to distinguish between whether you really need to know if it's "valid" or if you just need to decide whether to interpret it as a connection string or a file path. If it's the latter then you can make that decision without validating either. Then if you've decided it's a connection string but it can't be opened then it fails. (It probably doesn't matter whether it fails because it's not well-formed or if the server doesn't exist.) And same for file paths.

What about a very "low-tech" approach - if the parameter ends with `.xml` then it's an XML file. If not assume it's a connection string. You might want to account for a trailing quotation mark in case the file path contains a space. It might just be that simple. There's not much more you can do to account for invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the standard is to assume it is a file and then fall back to a raw value. The likelihood of overlap is low (unless you are naming your files with `;`) and the check for file existence is easy and cheap.

Answer (score 0):

There is [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-) class in .NET

It has a [constructor](http://us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts connection string as argument:
It will throw ArgumentException if connection string is not valid:

```
    try
    {
        var connectionSb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("your CS");
    }
    catch(ArgumentException e)
    {
        //Connection string is not valid
    }
```

For files you can use [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: That won't say whether the connection string is valid or not. The ConnectionString property only parses the semicolon-delimited list provided in conxString. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx. In theory SqlConnectionStringBuilder could provide validation, the MSDN documentation states that it simply inherits the base class implementation.

Comment: @EricJ. is correct, it just split into key-value pairs. For example: try `"ABC=1;DEF=2;DDD=3;"` it doesn't throw an exception.